# How do I join array of integers with an or(||) operator in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

so, the case is I have an array of integers say `[1,2,3,4]`.
I have to query for an api similar to this `api_query(x: 1 || 2 || 3 || 4)` or `api_query(x: "1" || "2" || "3" || "4")`. I am not able to figure out how to achieve this.

Using join produces something like this `"1 || 2 || 3 || 4"`, which doesn’t get the required output.

Comment: `1 || 2 || 3 || 4` is evaluated to `1` and `"1" || "2" || "3" || "4"` is evaluated to `"1"`, so this notation does not make much sense. Do you have an API documentation?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by join. Do you want to do a logical or on all of the elements of an array? Because that would just resolve to the first non nil value.

Comment: Can you share the API? Or the documentation? Without knowing either, this is a complete guess for us to say how you're supposed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the documentation of the API specifically accepts arrays for querying or "or" for querying you can't do this.

`a || b`will return the first "truthy" value so `1 || 2` will always return 1 because 1 is "truthy" (not false, not nil)

You can do this with separate api_query calls.

```
def get_first_match(*array)
  array.each do |element|
    match_test = ap_query(x: element)
    return match_test unless match_test['error'] # or whatever test for unsuccessful
  end
  nil
end
```

This lets you do

```
my_result = get_first_match(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

my_result will contain the first match or nil if no matches found.

Comment: oops `element` is outside the pipes `||`. Additionally `Enumerable#find` might be a better choice as it would avoid the return statement and the explicit `nil`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for the catch!  Block parameter fixed. 
 Enumerable#find will just return the element, though, so we'd need to do the ap_query twice, once in the find block and again using the successful result?  I think it's already an expensive method with `x` api calls, trying to avoid `x + 1`...